# Comment in java args

Tags: java, arguments

is it possible to comments into the java arguments for easier monitoring with programs that don't support the tree view?

`java -comment=app1 -jar app.jar`

Is there any way to include something that tells me which app it is, as all apps have the same name and getting started by a wrapper.

Comment: Could you use the "property" parameter `-Dcomment=app1` which can be accessed at runtime through `System.getProperty`?

Comment: You can also pass anything you want via the `-D` properties, app names, class names, ...

Comment: thanks, I think that will work.